# How to save a highChart in a specific file when clicking it in a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a requirement that i want to save a highchart as image in my local folder.I have created that .But my problem is that when i click on the button it is asking for the location ,i want to specify the path to which  i will save it.I am including a jsfiddle link here ,
So that you people can play.This is the button i am using for save it

```
   // the button handler
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.exportChart();
});
```

[fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-exportchart/)

I have searched the exportChart() function so that i can specify path in that,But have noot found any

Comment: Do you want to specific a local path?

Comment: How can you specific a local path for every user? You can't do this.

Comment: the specific path will be a folder inside my application so that i can use that image later.

Comment: and from where each users are coming ??

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Highchart.js API for exporting](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting), you can specific the path where save the chart and the file name.

```
exporting: {
        filename: 'your-file-name',
        url:'http://www.example.com/your-path'
    }
```

Here an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bellu/6hwt6e39/2/).

Comment: if i want to save it in the c drive then?? url:'c:/' this?because firefox is telling that it can not understand the address

Comment: Can you tell me  that what  i should write in the URL so that i can save it in my f drive??

Comment: @Bellu  In the URL you refers to server which convert SVG to image, but doens't save it there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup you own [exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) and develop saving chart into your server path.

Comment: how to do that can you help??

Comment: Unforutnatley Im not server developer, only javascript. So check how to save file in the phantomjs etc servers and return any URL.